# Can't delete recycling bin when code from svn is in it

Tags: svn

We use svn and when i want to remove a branch, i move it to the recycling bin and i keep getting an issue where i can't clear my recycling bin.

I keep getting the error:

"Cannot remove folder text-base: the directory is not empty."

has anyone seen this issue and are there any recommended solutions?

Comment: which interface are you using?  tortoiseSvn, etc..  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using TortoiseSvn, try killing TSVNCache.exe. It's probably still hanging on to one of the files in the text-base directory

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't recommend removing a branch unless you are absolutely certain you need to.  Even then I would wait a few weeks and make sure you don't use it again.

2) If you are using tortoiseSVN, just right-click on the folder containing the branch and go to the sub-menu for tortoise and select delete.  That should create a changelist to remove the branch.  Then just select SVN Commit.

Comment: He probably just wants to get rid of the working copy containing the branch, not the branch itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you move a branch to the recicle bin, you only delete the directory that contains the branch, not the branch itself. You must use the svn interface to delete the branch (as Lucas says)